# XNA Primitive rectangle has rotation issues

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to get some primitives working for XNA, including the ability to make outlined rectangles that can rotate. This is pretty useful, as you can do some sweet dynamic content creation with it, as well as it serving a debugging purpose.

The problem I am having can be seen [here](http://youtu.be/NcjqaFlefV0)

Essentially, what is happening is, when drawing an outlined rectangle, and turning the thickness of the line up past one, the lines that make up the rectangle move farther and farther away.

It's very strange but, I'm 90% sure that the problem lies in the origin. 
I'm hoping someone could take a look and spot my mistake.

I am rendering the rectangle by drawing rotated lines by setting the origin of the line to be what the center of the rectangle is. To achieve the bottom and right parts of the rectangle, I copy and rotate the top and left lines 180 degrees. (Pi if you are working in radians, which I am)

The biggest weirdness is that when I debug the `Draw` method I find the values are all exactly as expected!

Here's the rectangle class, the inherited classes are also below in case you need them.

```
public class Rectangle : Primitive
    {
        public float X { get { return Body.X; } set { Body.X = value; } }
        public float Y { get { return Body.Y; } set { Body.Y = value; } }
        public float Width { get { return Body.Width; } set { Body.Width = value; } }
        public float Height { get { return Body.Height; } set { Body.Height = value; } }
        public float Angle { get { return Body.Angle; } set { Body.Angle = value; } }


        public override Vector2 Bounds { get { return new Vector2((Width) * Scale.X, (Height) * Scale.Y);}}

        public override Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle DrawRect
        {
            get
            {
                return new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle((int) (X - Thickness/2), (int) (Y - Thickness/2),
                                                             (int) ((X + Width + Thickness) * Scale.X),
                                                             (int) ((Y + Height + Thickness)* Scale.Y));
            }
        }

        public bool Fill;

        public Rectangle(Entity parent, string name, float x, float y, float width, float height, bool fill = false)
            : base(parent, name)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            Fill = fill;

            Origin = new Vector2(.5f,.5f);
        }

        public Rectangle(IComponent parent, string name, Body body, bool fill) : base(parent, name, body)
        {
            Fill = fill;
            Origin = new Vector2(.5f, .5f);
        }

        public override void Draw(SpriteBatch sb)
        {
            base.Draw(sb);
            if (!Fill)
            {
                float minx = X + (Thickness/2) + Origin.X;
                float miny = Y + (Thickness/2) +Origin.Y;
                //TODO: Fix origin issue
                //Draw our top line
                sb.Draw(Assets.Pixel,
                        new Vector2(minx, miny), null, Color * Alpha, Angle, new Vector2(Origin.X, Origin.Y * Bounds.Y), new Vector2(Bounds.X, Thickness * Scale.Y), Flip, Layer);

                //Left line
                sb.Draw(Assets.Pixel,
                        new Vector2(minx, miny), null, Color * Alpha, Angle, new Vector2(Origin.X * Bounds.X, Origin.Y), new Vector2(Thickness * Scale.X, Bounds.Y), Flip, Layer);


                //Essentially these are the same as the top and bottom just rotated 180 degrees
                //I have to do it this way instead of setting the origin to a negative value because XNA
                //seems to ignore origins when they are negative
                //Right Line
                sb.Draw(Assets.Pixel,
                        new Vector2(minx + 1, miny), null, Color * Alpha, Angle + MathHelper.Pi, new Vector2(Origin.X * Bounds.X, Origin.Y), new Vector2(Thickness * Scale.X, Bounds.Y), Flip, Layer);

                //Bottom Line
                sb.Draw(Assets.Pixel,
                        new Vector2(minx, miny + 1), null, Color * Alpha, Angle + MathHelper.Pi, new Vector2(Origin.X, Origin.Y * Bounds.Y), new Vector2(Bounds.X, Thickness * Scale.Y), Flip, Layer);

            }
            else
            {
                sb.Draw(Assets.Pixel, new Vector2(X + Origin.X*Width, Y + Origin.Y*Height), null, Color * Alpha, Angle, Origin, Bounds - new Vector2(Thickness), Flip, Layer);
            }
        }
```

`Primitive`

```
public abstract class Primitive : Render
    {
        public Body Body;

        public float Thickness = 1;

        protected Primitive(IComponent parent, string name) : base(parent, name)
        {
            Body = new Body(this, "Primitive.Body");   
        }

        protected Primitive(IComponent parent, string name, Vector2 pos)
            : base(parent, name)
        {
            Body = new Body(this, "Primitive.Body", pos);
        }

        protected Primitive(IComponent parent, string name, Body body) : base(parent, name)
        {
            Body = body;
        }

        public static void DrawLine(SpriteBatch sb, Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2, float thickness, float layer, Color color)
        {
            float angle = (float)System.Math.Atan2(p2.Y - p1.Y, p2.X - p1.X);
            float length = Vector2.Distance(p1, p2);

            sb.Draw(Assets.Pixel, p1, null, color,
                    angle, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(length, thickness),
                    SpriteEffects.None, layer);
        }
    }
```

`Render` class. This one isn't as important as it is just there to give some sort of polymorphism to any rendering class.

```
    using EntityEngineV4.Engine;
using EntityEngineV4.PowerTools;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace EntityEngineV4.Components.Rendering
{
    public abstract class Render : Component
    {
        public float Alpha = 1f;
        public Color Color = Color.White;
        public SpriteEffects Flip = SpriteEffects.None;
        public float Layer;
        public Vector2 Scale = Vector2.One;

    public Vector2 Origin;

    /// <summary>
    /// Handy rectangle for getting the drawing position
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Rectangle DrawRect { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Source rectangle of the texture
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Rectangle SourceRect { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bounds of the DrawRect
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Vector2 Bounds { get; set; }

    protected Render(IComponent parent, string name)
        : base(parent, name)
    {
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gt)
    {
        base.Update(gt);
    }

    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch sb = null)
    {
        base.Draw(sb);
    }
    }
}
```

If you have any questions, don't be afraid to ask!

Answer (score 0):

You should divide origin by the scale.

```
var scale = new Vector2(Bounds.X, Thickness * Scale.Y);
var origin = new Vector2(Origin.X, Origin.Y * Bounds.Y) / scale;
sb.Draw(Assets.Pixel, new Vector2(minx, miny), null, Color * Alpha, 
        Angle, origin, scale, Flip, Layer);
```

Though I think you are doing things a bit complicated... I would use a transform matrix to transform the drawed rectangle...

```
  public void DrawBorder( Rectangle Bounds, int ThickNess, float angle, Color color ) {
        Vector3 Origin = new Vector3( Bounds.Width, Bounds.Height, 0 ) * 0.5f;
        Vector3 Pos = new Vector3( Bounds.X, Bounds.Y, 0 );

        Matrix transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation( -Origin ) 
                         * Matrix.CreateRotationZ( angle ) 
                         * Matrix.CreateTranslation( Pos );
        Batch.Begin( SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, transform );

        Bounds.X = 0;
        Bounds.Y = 0;
        Rectangle aux = Bounds;

        Bounds.X -= ThickNess;
        Bounds.Width = ThickNess;
        Batch.Draw( Batch.WhiteTexture, Bounds, color );
        Bounds.X = aux.Right;
        Batch.Draw( Batch.WhiteTexture, Bounds, color );

        Bounds.Y = aux.Top - ThickNess;
        Bounds.X = aux.Left - ThickNess;
        Bounds.Width = aux.Width + 2 * ThickNess;
        Bounds.Height = ThickNess;

        Batch.Draw( Batch.WhiteTexture, Bounds, color );

        Bounds.Y = aux.Bottom;

        Batch.Draw( Batch.WhiteTexture, Bounds, color );

        Batch.End( );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a try. I'll check into the matrix thing, I already use one for my camera, and I take it at the first `spritebatch.Draw`. I didn't know you could rotate single objects with a matrix, and this would certainly make my life easier. :)

Comment: I looked up the matrix thing, and I think it would be more trouble than it's worth. Also, your solution didn't seem to fix the problem :(

Comment: The scale affects to the origin... I though that division would fix it... I have added the code with a matrix... I assume that the origin is the center of the rectangle... but is easy to change it if you want to rotate about an arbitrary origin.

Comment: Essentially, I had to make a way for it to be easier to change the origin, since it would allow for different rotation points. I'll take a look at your matrix code :)